# jQuery plugin for datatables

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatable

I am working on a datatable which is not very big and I need to implement the following UI

- Draggable Columns
- Resizable Columns
- UI has to have memory across sessions.

I have gone through the list of jQuery plugins for datatables and I am not really satisfied with what I was getting.

Things like flexigrid and others with YUI or EXTJS are obviously an overkill for this.

There are simple solutions for making draggable columns but none of them has all the features that I want.

Does anybody know of a plugin that might help?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQgrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) will do the trick very well.

Comment: The columns aren't draggable on this one.